# Link the object to hibernate session

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Can someone please help me?
I have a hibernate situation where I'm retrieving the object from a view and doing a manual mapping to convert it to an object and then trying to attach that object back to session. For this I'm using lock. It is working fine but in some cases I'm retrieving the object twice and the lock happens twice and it gives error that the same key is already in session. Is there any other way to attach object to a session?
Note:my code is using nhibernate v1, as it is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

the NHibernate-Session hast to make sure that unique rows from the DataBase are unique within itself, meaning two things

1. if you have the same objects of the same class in two variables and use object.ReferenceEquals on them then they return true, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-6.0. You should lookup reference-types verses value-types if you are not sure about Equals VS ReferenceEquals.
2. to optimize (aka. avoid if possible) to access the database, meaning that it will look up an object by it's key in memory if possible.

So you are 100% stuck with having one object per key/session/class combination.
You have to change your code that is loading/converting the data from the view. You have to look up the object is already in memory with the given key and return that object from memory instead of creating a new object, if you already find it. You have to decide between two options how to handle the new data from the view:

- discard it! You already have that data in memory. (I would prefer that.)
- update the object in memory, map into the object instead of into a new object. (Be careful, that would "override" all changes that have already been made in memory but not jet committed to the database - and with NHibernate you can never be sure if or if not.)

How too look up an object by it's class and key in an NHibernate Session ... I do not know from memory, but I am sure you'll find that quickly.

Greetings

Juy Juka